# Why am i getting this error while running my C code file in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

Was trying to setup my visual studio code to run the c file. I setup the environment variables correctly. I install the C/C++ extensions.

[image: here is my code]

`"Cannot build and debug because the active file is not a C or C++ source file."`

This error prompt when i try to run the code.

Comment: have you tried the C/C++-tutorial in the VSC docs

Comment: ya I tried. still same issue and error

Comment: Have you tried killing the vs-code process and restarting the editor?

Comment: which is your active file

Comment: Have you saved the file with a `.c` file extension?

Answer (score 0):

1. I recommend new project on visual stdio
2. when you make Source file

2-1) check intall visual C++

2-2) click C++file(cpp) //it is Compiled translation source files

2-3) make file name :  ~~.c  (extension called .c)

2-4) check your file path

2-5) add Source file

!!!A file name cannot contain any of the following characters

like \ / : * ? " < > |